# If I use any text with "eval" in it the page throws a PHP error (e.g. "evaluation")

Tags: ee2, wygwam

I'm using WYGWAM 2.7 and expressionengine 2.5.5.
I get this error:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Please contact support about failure

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 683

If the word "evaluation" is used in my WYGWAM channel field. If I take it out the page works fine.

Comment: Is your page set to parse PHP? Does it need to?

Comment: Can you check if mod_security is running? If so, please disable it and try this again; that's the most common issue I've seen with this symptom. Thank you!

Comment: The page isn't set to parse PHP and it does not need to. I tried adding <IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule> to my .htaccess file but that threw errors.

Comment: What errors, Andy? You may need to ask your host to try disabling it; they may have disabled disabling for security reasons.  Clear as mud?